# Using al.exe to sign an assembly:

Tags: .net, interop

This command fails:

```
al.exe /out:ClassLibrary3.dll Class3.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk
```

And I don't know why.  Here's how it fails on the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>al.exe /
out:ClassLibrary3.dll Class3.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk
Microsoft (R) Assembly Linker version 10.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ALINK: error AL1047: Error importing file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
        SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Class3.netmodule' -- The system
        cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>
```

Class3 is the only class in my assembly.  Is this looking for some physical "Class3.netmodule" file or object in a directory or something?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command, specifically, is trying to generate an assembly from a netmodule. So yes, it is looking for a physical file named "Class3.netmodule".

You can't arbitrarily sign an assembly from the command line. You must either sign it during compile time; or, if set for delay-signing, use `sn.exe -R[a]`.

Comment: vcsjones, thank you for replying to this.  This is information I didn't know.  Are you saying that if I'm building this in VS 2010, that this command actually takes place during that build time?  (And if so, where in the VS environment do I write that?)  Thank you again, and for any further guidance.

Comment: Okay, even though my project is in VB.NET, I went to Solution Explorer!Properties and clicked the Signing tab on the left.  Then checked the "Sign the assembly" box, and selected a strong name key file into that field.  I built the dll, then used gacutil.exe on it and got command line feedback that the assembly had been successfully added to the cache.  So hopefully more or less the same happened with that as if I'd written the project using MSVC.